# Problema video en angular

Tags: angular

**ANGULAR**
No anda el muted cuando inserto el video en un componente. Se reproduce etc pero con sonido

```
<video muted #video autoplay preload="auto" width="100%" height="100%">
    <source src="../../../assets/video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
 </video>
```

Tambien probe desde el componente con **elementRef** y **ViewChild** de la siguiente forma

```
  @ViewChild('video', { static: true})
  video: HTMLVideoElement;


  ngOnInit(){
    this.video.muted
    this.video.volume = 0
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu aproximación es correcta, solo te faltan algunos detalles. Cuando usas ViewChild recuerda que recibes una instancia de `ElementRef` esta a su vez contiene una propiedad `nativeElement`. Entonces tienes que acceder a esa propiedad antes de acceder a la propiedad `muted`. Te recomiendo `static:true` para que puedas acceder al elemento una vez que se ha creado la vista.

```
 @ViewChild("video", { static: true, read: ElementRef })
 video: ElementRef;

 ngOnInit() {
    this.video.nativeElement.muted = true;
  }
```

Comment: Gracias, me funciono perfecto! me queda una duda, porque funciona con elementRef, pero no con HTMLVideoElement. Ya que este ultimo contiene todas las propiedades y metodos del tipo video, pausar mutear etc